# Node.js : Want to use separate database for new client in my Saas application

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express, database-design

I am working on a SaaS application(Node.js + AngularJS + mySql). All clients are using a common database and common app server. One of the clients requires a separate database.
In the present scenario, When the server starts, I create mySql pool variable with host, user and password in a file name `commonRouter.js`. Like below:-

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: '',
    host: '<host IP>',
    user: '',
    password: '',
    database: '<database_name>'
});
exports.mysql_pool = pool;
```

And on each API call I retrieve pool variable from `commonRouter.js` file like below:

```
commonRouter.mysql_pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
  // do database operations.
});
```

The problem with me that how I will decide that which database should I hit for any client if there are multiple databases.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.